# Why do BCrypt hashes store information about version and iterations?

Tags: algorithm, hash, bcrypt

BCrypt hashes usually begin with some repeating symbols.

Lets say for example we see `$2a$10` as a beginning of our hash.Every BCrypt hash has something similar to this.

`$` is a separator

`2a` is in this case the version

`10` is the number of iterations 2 to the power of 10

My question is - why is this information in the hash?

There is no dehashing algorithm that might need this information in particular and when people log-in they generate the same has using the same version and the same number of iterations and then the result is compared to what is stored in the database. This means that the algorithm doesn't have build in comparing function that gets the has and based on this information (version and iterations) hashes the password to make the comparison.

Then...why is it so that this information is given away? Who uses this information?

My guess is so that if the version has changed or the number of iterations our program or whatever will know,  but...why? I mean that the algorithm must be configured only once and if changes are required then it is the company's job to make the appropriate arrangements so that it knows what version was used and what is used now. Why is it the hash's job to remember the version and number of iterations?

Hashes get leaked every week or so and with this information someone can easily set up his BCrypt and make it running with the same configuration of version and iterations...however if this information wasn't visible in the hash and the hash got public...then how would anyone make their own BCrypt version and start comparing it?

Isn't it more safe to not provide this information so that if the hash alone gets leaked nobody would know what configuration was used to make it?

Comment: If you don't need it, just strip it off. I need that information because as computing power increases, I increase the number of iterations. There would be no way for me to know how many iterations to use for an existing hash if I don't store that information somewhere. Whether it's stored in the hash or in an additional column in the database makes absolutely no difference from a security perspective.

Comment: It is there because over time (system maintenance) it may change. You cannot upgrade old password records to the new scheme without the users actual password. This means, your system has to support several versions and iterations at the same time.

Comment: I am not saying its a bad thing - I am thinking why it has to be in the hash. As for security - why store it in the database? In most cases you have a function that when you log in gets the hash and sees this information and based on this decides how to hash the password. Why not store the change in this function as a parameter? You store the time frame for which a current version was active (from May to June in 2017 for example) and when someone registers you save the date he registered.

Comment: Then your function gets the date of registration (or last password update) and checks if the date matches any time frame. If it does - it uses the settings that were used during this time frame. This way if the database gets stolen and becomes public people won't be able to match it with their hashes because they don't know the settings. Then your only concern is to limit access to this function which is not that hard to do. And even if you fail and they get access to this function which does the log-in - you are where you started with - a hash and versions, so you don't loose anything

Comment: So if you use this technique you can't make your security worse but you can limit data breaches to not be so fatal if they do happen.This is why my question is - why is it the hash's job to remember? There are other ways which make it harder to get all of the information. Still possible but if you make it harder and you fail - you are just where you started, and nothing worse has happened

Comment: So just strip off the prefix and store that information in whatever way you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes bcrypt forward and backwards compatible.

For example, bcrypt hashes do **not** start with `2a`.

They start with:

- `$2$`
- `$2a`
- `$2x$`
- `$2y$`
- `$2b$`

You need to know which version of the has you're reading, so you handle it correctly.

Also, you need to know the number of iterations.

- not every hash will use `10`
- not every hash will use the same cost

Why store the version and iterations? Because you have to.

Also, it's an excellent. In the past, people used to just store a hash, and it was awful.

- people used either no salt, or the same salt every time, because storing it was too hard
- people uses 1 iteration, or a hard-coded number of iterations, because storing it was too hard

BCrypt, SCrypt, and Argon2 use the extraordinarily clever idea of doing all that grunt-work for you, leaving you with only having to call one function, without weakening the security of the system in any way.

Answer (score 0):

- you're trying to preach security by obscurity.  Stop that, it doesn't work.
- not having details in the data is not unusual, in [this old hack](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/8q88k5/hackers-stole-68-million-passwords-from-tumblr-new-analysis-reveals) it was hackers that mentioned it was SHA1.  This is easy - the attackers, and researchers too, will take the list of data that was leaked and simply try all kinds of common algorithms and interation/work factor counts with a small list of the common passwords, like the [phpbb list from SkullSecurity](https://wiki.skullsecurity.org/Passwords); when they find the inevitable cracked terrible, passwords, they'll know they found the algorithm and break out the full scale cracking.
- having the algorithm stored means you can transition from old to new gradually, and upgrade individual users as they come in, AND have multiple variants in use at one - including transitional types

  - transitional: you were on salted SHA-1 (BAD), moving to PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512 with 200,000 iterations (good), in the middle you actually bulk convert to PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512(SHA-1(salted password)), but at each user's login, move them to pure PBKDF2-HMAC-SHA-512(password).
- having the iteration count means, like the transitional above, you can increase it over time and have different counts for different users set as they log in.